# How to get state and city using placeid in Google Map Api in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

How to get state and city using place_id. I want to get state and city using place_id. t

Please see the following link [Google_map](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyDMJVEN6yD_nfxWGsOZttouWAFBHczbh0w&placeid=ChIJLfyY2E4UrjsRVq4AjI7zgRY), I want to get state and city of following place_id **"place_id" : "ChIJLfyY2E4UrjsRVq4AjI7zgRY",**

Comment: State and city aren't details returned in the places api response, so I'm not sure if you can retrieve them consistently. You can try parsing it from the address, but that might be unreliable.

Answer (score 4):

[Google Place Details response](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) contains `address_components[] field` which represents an array of separate address components used to compose a given address, you could extract city and state from this property.

According to [Address Component Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingAddressTypes):

> - `administrative_area_level_1` -  *indicates a first-order civil entity below the country level. Within the United States, these
>     administrative levels are states. Not all nations exhibit these
>     administrative levels.*
> - `locality` - *indicates an incorporated city or town political entity.*

**Example**

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
        placeId: 'ChIJLfyY2E4UrjsRVq4AjI7zgRY'
    }, function (place, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            /*var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });*/
            showPlaceDetails(map, place, infowindow);
        }
    });
}


function showPlaceDetails(map, place, infowindow) {
    //parse address details
    var info = '';
    place.address_components.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.types.indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") > -1) {
            info += '<div>State: ' + item.long_name + '</div>';
        }
        if (item.types.indexOf("locality") > -1) {
            info += '<div>City: ' + item.long_name + '</div>';
        }
    });
    infowindow.setContent(info);
    infowindow.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    infowindow.open(map);
}
```

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#map {
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: This implementation is in Javascript. But I need Angular-Google-Map